# What do the silks and tattoos represent in Sui-Yun's poem about Eve?

Tags: poetry, symbolism, spanish-language, sui-yun

One of the Peruvian writer Sui-Yun's [Four Short Poems](https://www.wordswithoutborders.org/article/september-2020-asian-peruvian-four-poems-sui-yun-jennifer-shyue) (translated from Spanish by Jennifer Shyue) is written as addressed to "Eve, my eternal mother".

I hope I'm not being excessively dirty-minded in reading the verse about "licking the tip of evil" as a sexual reference: particularly in light of the poems as a whole being described as meditations "on sin and sensual pleasure", and the last two containing more blatant sexual imagery. But the rest of the poem is more confusing to me:

> To turn away from evil
> I’ve crammed my jars full
> of somber recollections
> calling to the unknown silks
> radiating from my body
>
> To turn away from evil
> I’ve added every letter of your body
> to my body, tattooing myself whole.

The "jars" presumably refers to jars of memory, being filled with recollections to remind the speaker to turn away from evil. But what are the "unknown silks radiating from my body"?

The last verse is even stranger: why would the speaker tattoo every letter of Eve onto her body? What does this represent? How does it (or for that matter the things described in the earlier verses) help her to erase sins or "turn away from evil"?

Do the jars, silks, and tattoos actually symbolise something else? Is there some biblical significance, perhaps relating to the original story of Adam and Eve?

Comment: My lunch break is over so I shan’t delve into this right now, but this book seems a promising avenue https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=OP-EBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA144&lpg=PA144&dq=%22sui-yun%22+poet+peruvian&source=bl&ots=hKqdDAH3Wa&sig=ACfU3U1MS-bRhBzMOHymsmzzfJjAZetwjQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjQqISsofDrAhXTNcAKHX4GCOg4ChDoATAQegQIBRAB#v=onepage&q=%22sui-yun%22%20poet%20peruvian&f=false

Comment: @Spagirl That page isn't viewable from my location, but from surrounding pages I see it has something about Sui-Yun. Does it say something about this specific poem?

Comment: Alas, it won’t let me see it now either. The book was called ‘Dragons in the Land of the Condor: Writing Tusán in Peru’ if that helps at all. The page I lit on made reference to Sui-Yun’s identifying more closely with the natural world than any national culture, and some reference to Christianity (possibly rejection of). I wondered if silks were a reference to Chinese traditional clothing.

Comment: @Spagirl I don't know much about the poet's background. She's described as Peruvian, but her name seems more Chinese. These four poems were part of [a collection](https://www.wordswithoutborders.org/article/september-2020-a-slice-of-writing-by-nikkei-and-tusan-peruvian-writers) by "Asian Peruvian" writers, whatever that means. Might be some interesting background to dig into, if you're right that cultural references are involved here. (The Girl With The Eve Tattoo???)

Comment: apparently there is a significant sino-Peruvian literary community. Which is just one of the many things I’ve learned today! https://www.ubcpress.ca/dragons-in-the-land-of-the-condor

Comment: btw the name Sui-Yun is a pseudonym, the author’s actual name apparently being Katie Wong Loo. Source http://ignaciolopezcalvo.blogspot.com/2013/01/latin-america-and-caribbean-in.html?m=1

Comment: It's interesting how this translation differs from the original - the original is not dedicated to Eve, and the last verse has an additional three lines.